# Angular2 / NodeJS file uploader. req.files not present

Tags: node.js, file, angular

I am currently developing an application in Angular2 which is wrapped by in a NodeJS instance which talks to an API. I am currently implementing some file upload functionality and cannot get a function which captures the API file upload request in the NodeJS layer to show that it is catching the files. There is no 'files' property on the 'req' object.

Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { routes } from "../../../routes";
import { FilesService } from "../../../services/files.service";

@Component({
    selector    : 'file-upload',
    moduleId    : module.id,
    templateUrl : '/app/views/files/file-upload.html',
})

export class FileUploaderDirective {
    private _filesToUpload: Array<File> = [];

    constructor(
        private _filesService: FilesService
    ) {

    }

    fileChangeEvents(fileInput: any) {
        this._filesToUpload = <Array<File>> fileInput.target.files;
    }

    upload() {
        this._filesService.sendFile(routes.api.files, [], this._filesToUpload)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
}
```

MY file upload Angular2 service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class FilesService {

    constructor() {

    }

    sendFile(url: String, vars: Array<String>, files: File[]): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let formData: FormData  = new FormData(),
                xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name);
            }

            xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                    } else {
                        reject(xhr.response);
                    }
                }
            };

            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            xhr.send(formData);
        });
    }
```

}

The NodeJS route that catches the api request and forwards it to a controller function in NodeJS:

```
router.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
    filesRoutesControllerObjectInstance.upload(req, res, next);
});
```

And the function which is supposed to catch the request and send the files to the API:

```
var ApiBase_RequestLayer = require('../ApiBase_RequestLayer'),
    Config = require(global.appRoot + '/Config'),
    util = require('util');

function Files() {
    Files.super_.call(this);
    this.requestBaseUrl = Config.brain.url + '/upload';
}

Files.prototype.upload = function(req, res) {
    if(req) {

    }
};

util.inherits(Files, ApiBase_RequestLayer);

module.exports = Files;
```

When I debug the request there is no files present on the request when I debug the 'req' object in the NodeJS 'uoload' route and the controller. As you can see I am attempting to send them using the FormData Angular2 functionality. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Have you tried using any kind of `multipart/form-data` express middleware. I'm making the assumption that you are using express.

Comment: No I haven't. I am using Express yes. Can you recommend a good middleware to investigate?

Comment: Plus the req.files property isn't present when the first NodeJS route is hit so it seems as if Angular2 is sending the files?

Comment: Busboy, multiparty or formidable... whichever suits your needs better check [npm compare](https://npmcompare.com/compare/busboy,formidable,multer,multiparty)